# Is there a way to switch web versions of Navier/Kakao maps to English?

Tags: online-resources, south-korea, maps

Can one switch [Naver](https://map.naver.com/) and/or [Kakao](https://map.kakao.com/) maps to English? I mean specifically web versions for browsers, not mobile apps.

Comment: Did you know that [Google maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Seoul) has translations added?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. But Google maps are unusable in/for South Korea.

Comment: Did you find [Finally Naver Maps English version is here](https://www.reddit.com/r/korea/comments/7sdf37/finally_naver_maps_english_version_is_here/)? Or is that for app? There are a lot of resources to explore.

Comment: @WeatherVane I saw that topic, but I don't know whether that applies to the app only or to the web version also. I was able to install the app in English, but I wasn't able to switch the web version to English.

Comment: Google maps works fine in Korea. It's not as accurate as Korean maps, but it works fine. I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: @insidesin But I can't use it from the US to browse the map of Korea and plan the trip since Korea is blurred on Google Maps.

Comment: Blurred? What do you mean? They don't let you view Korea?

Comment: @insidesin I thought this is a well-known issue. E.g. see [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleMaps/comments/boxj6l/why_does_the_map_for_south_korea_look_so/). I can view the map, but the icons of almost all businesses are unclickable.

Comment: Yeah I see this "issue" a lot, but then I have lived in Korea and every time I open Google maps I can manage to get around fine with it. It's limited compared to most countries but it's also very useful. Having Google Map icons (i.e. commercial places) not clickable isn't really a huge fault...

Comment: If you type in places, they show up. If for some reason 80% functionality is not enough for you to plan, then KakaoMaps is the way to go.

Comment: @insidesin It's true that I can type in places, but in that case I already should know the places that I am to type in. So I can't use Google Maps to find out what places I might want to visit. I would argue that this reduces functionality by more than 20%. As for KakaoMaps, I know that I can use them, but in any case whether or not I can use KakaoMaps or whether Google Maps work in Korea is not what the question is about.

Comment: I would say that if you're mainly using Google Maps to browse places in a foreign country to visit, then you're using the map wrong. It's going to give you very bad places to visit compared to any Korean listings. Google Maps definitely works in Korea and the explore part of Google Maps is not more than 20% of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **no**, this is currently impossible. There are guidelines on how to use [Naver's mobile app](https://www.nitaro.net/2019/06/how-to-use-naver-in-english/) or [Kakao's mobile app](http://www.ulsanonline.com/culture/how-to-use-kakao-maps-in-english/) in English, but those methods don't work for their desktop app unfortunately.